# Set of Preference

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I want to send a formal email to describe my order of preference of some courses that I want to study. Is it correct to say :

With the following set of preference:

1. course a
2. course b
3. course c

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate on our English Language Learners site.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite certain what you wish to say?  Is this your order of preferences?  Because you'd say:  I prefer the following in order:

Comment: @DavidM ,yes it is my order of preferences. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More usual would be "*in the following order of preference:*"